# Node data is empty after creation in go-zookeeper

Tags: go, apache-zookeeper

Data posted to zookeeper from go on creation is empty.
I use the library `github.com/go-zookeeper/zk`.

I create the node with:

```
Name, _ = c.Create("/auth/nodes", publicKey, zk.FlagEphemeral|zk.FlagSequence, config.ZOO_OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE)
```

and read the data with:

```
b, _, _ := c.Get("/auth/" + Name)
```

After creation the data is empty. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Don't ignore errors.

Comment: Ignored them by thinking I would do error handling later, turns out I shouldn't have. I was using the wrong path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong path. The correct one is

```
b, _, err := c.Get(Name)
```

And I should have handled the errors from Get to see what's going on.